# snmptrapd : Authentication failed for

Tags: python, virtualbox, net-snmp, snmptrapd

I have a python script (using pysnmp lib) running on a real device with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which do internal polling. It sends keepalives and SNMPv3 Traps to Nagios. Snmptrapd is receiving traps and passing it to Snmptt, which works very well.

Ive been trying the same scenario in VirtualBox with same distr. Ubuntu 14.04
but on Nagios side all the Time i get

> snmptrapd[7540]: Authentication failed for hostname

I couldnt figure out what is the problem. Capturing with Wireshark, i can see both packets are coming in, from the real host and virtualbox guesthost. With createUser derivative, i add two users with same engineId,SHA and AES encryp but only keepalives as well as SNMPv3 Traps from Real Host are logged and past to SNMPTT but not from VirtualBox.

Is there anything iam missing ?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
disableAuthorization yes
```

in the /etc/sysconfig/snmptrapd.conf on nagios.